# Horizontal viewport was given unbounded

Tags: flutter

[image: Screenshot]

I am trying to perform a pageview swipe but got the following error above. Please help me solve this problem.

errors:

```
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {

  List<Coffee> coffeeList = List<Coffee>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.coffeeList.add(new Coffee('../images/cup_of_coffee.png', 'Cappuccino', 'Coffee 1', 329.0));
    this.coffeeList.add(new Coffee('../images/cup_of_coffee.png', 'Caffè Americano', 'Coffee 2', 299.0));
    this.coffeeList.add(new Coffee('../images/cup_of_coffee.png', 'Espresso', 'Lattes', 249.0));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromARGB(1, 237, 231, 230),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Select',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
              ),
              Text(
                'Coffee',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          PageView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _pageItem(coffeeList, index),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _pageItem(List<Coffee> coffeeList, int index) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Image.asset(coffeeList[index].url),
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(coffeeList[index].category,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(1, 237, 231, 230),
                )),
            Text(coffeeList[index].title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ],
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(coffeeList[index].price.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}

PageController _pageViewController() {}

class Coffee {
  String url, category, title;
  double price;

  Coffee(this.url, this.category, this.title, this.price);
}
```

Comment: Add a screenshot please

Comment: i have added it

Comment: Try adding the controller property to the page view builder. I can you see have a page controller defined but not attached to the PageView.builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Expanded flex` to provider `height`

```
Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Column(
...         
Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: PageView.builder(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  List<Coffee> coffeeList = List<Coffee>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.coffeeList.add(new Coffee(
        'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', 'Cappuccino', 'Coffee 1', 329.0));
    this.coffeeList.add(new Coffee('https://picsum.photos/250?image=10',
        'Caffè Americano', 'Coffee 2', 299.0));
    this.coffeeList.add(new Coffee(
        'https://picsum.photos/250?image=11', 'Espresso', 'Lattes', 249.0));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color.fromARGB(1, 237, 231, 230),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Select',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Coffee',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: coffeeList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  _pageItem(coffeeList, index),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _pageItem(List<Coffee> coffeeList, int index) {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Image.network(coffeeList[index].url),
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(coffeeList[index].category,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(1, 237, 231, 230),
                )),
            Text(coffeeList[index].title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ],
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            coffeeList[index].price.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}

PageController _pageViewController() {}

class Coffee {
  String url, category, title;
  double price;

  Coffee(this.url, this.category, this.title, this.price);
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: "test",
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: HomeView(),
    );
  }
}
```